nestjs pgsql typeorm is not updating the updated_at date nodejs
I am using nestjs with typeorm and i have created the following common entity, any other entity can extend this and have basic fields like created_at and updated_at
but on updating/creating entry on table it is not upating correct date in updated_at
export class CommonEntity extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    name: "created_at", type: "timestamptz", select: true,
    default: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nullable: true
  })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ name: "created_by", nullable: true, type: "integer", select: false })
  createdBy: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity) // Establish Many-to-One relationship
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'created_by', referencedColumnName: 'id' }) // Specify the join column
  createdByUser: UserEntity;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    name: "updated_at", type: "timestamptz", select: true,
    onUpdate: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", default: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nullable: true
  })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @Column({ name: "updated_by", type: "integer", select: false, nullable: true, })
  updatedBy: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity) // Establish Many-to-One relationship
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'updated_by', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  updatedByUser: UserEntity;
}

like this i have following entity
export class EnquiryDocEntity extends CommonEntity {

  @Column({ name: "name", enum: EnquiryDocName, nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({ name: "enquiry_id", type: "integer", select: false })
  enquiryId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => EnquiryEntity) // Establish Many-to-One relationship
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'enquiry_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' }) // Specify the join column
  enquiryInfo: EnquiryEntity;

  @Column({ name: "url", type: "varchar", nullable: false })
  url: string;
}

and on upload i am using this
const existingDoc = await this.enquiryDocRepo.findOne({
        where:
          { name: enquiryDocDto.name, enquiryId: enquiryDocDto.enquiryId }
      });

      if (existingDoc) {

        // If a document with the same name exists, update it
        this.s3Service.deleteObject(existingDoc.url);
        existingDoc.url = enquiryDocDto.url;
        const updatedDoc = await this.enquiryDocRepo.save(existingDoc);
        return { data: updatedDoc };
      } else {
        // If no document with the same name exists, insert a new record
        const newDoc = await this.enquiryDocRepo.save(enquiryDocDto);
        return { data: newDoc };
      }

i am uploading it today (08/04/2024) but this is showing old date 22/03/2024 in updated_at when new entry is getting created but on upating the same then it updates the updated_at correctly

Are you sure there is an actual change in the entity? see https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9276
